# Is it always necessary to wait for every thread to terminate before actually closing main one?

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose I have a main thread and a normal thread, whose execution lasts more than the former one.

Something like it:

```
public class Test{
     private int count;

     public void doTest(){
        (new MyThread()).start();

     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
           Test t = new Test();
           t.doTest();
     }

     private class MyThread extends Thread{
            public void run(){
                 while(count < 100){
                     count++;
                     ..wait some secs ...
                 }

            }

     }
```

}

Is it wrong to just leave code like that? Or would it be more correct perform a join() on the thread so to make sure that  it  correctly ends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is one of the question, for which the answer is: *It depends.*

There is no technical reason to have the main thread running till all other threads are terminated. In fact, you can handle the main thread like every other thread. As I recommend to not have a thread keeping alive when it already has done its business and can be terminated, a main thread that only starts other threads should simply terminate after starting the others.

Remind: The JVM itself is not terminated when the main thread terminates. The JVM will only terminate when all non-daemon threads are terminated.

Comment: +1.. you are right.. making a *join* in this case would be *inefficient*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you maybe also looking for a scenario when it is **"not okay to exit before all thread exit" / "wait till all threads exit, and then exit the main program"**.

While developing games, at least in java , we do need to take care that all thread exit before the main program exits . If you ask why, then let me explain you with an example which should clear things for you.

If there are 3 threads, controlling different aspects of game.

Thread 1: Controls the game background sounds/music/audio.

Thread 2: Controls the Artificial intelligence .

Thread 3: Controls the Graphics Rendering .

And consider this scenario, if the user closes his game, and if the threads are not waited upon before closing then there can a be case where in the main window of the game is closed i.e. Thread 2, Thread 3 but not Thread 1. So you will have the game music still playing even when the game window is not seen. That would be pretty embarrassing for any game developer.

Answer (score 1):

It is **perfectly fine**.

No `join` or `System.exit` necessary.

Each thread lives its own life. As long as at least one thread is running, the program keeps running.

Answer (score 1):

The JVM will automatically exit [as soon as there are no more non-daemon threads running](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html).

If you don't call [setDaemon(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)) before launching the thread, the JVM will automatically exit when your Thread is done. No need to call `join()` on the Thread, if all you want is for the process to end as soon as your thread ends.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the thread runs in an endless loop, it will end at some time, the question is whether you want to wait for the termination of that thread or not? You may want to wait If the further processing depends on the result of thread you have started. If that thread just does some work and ends then just leave it.